# Как при создании структуры внутри макроса сгенерировать ее имя из переданного в макрос значения?

Tags: c, gcc, макрос, метапрограммирование

```
#define EXAMPLE_MACRO(val_type, postfix) \
    struct example_struct_postfix {      \
        val_type val;                                     \
    }; 

EXAMPLE_MACRO(int, name);
```

Я хочу чтоб в данном примере, было сгенерировано example_struct_name, но генерируется example_struct_postfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так: `example_struct_##postfix`.

---

Если передать в качестве имени другой макрос, то будет взято имя макроса, а не его значение. Т.е.: `#define A B` `EXAMPLE_MACRO(int, A)` -> `example_struct_A`.

Если это мешает, то так:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y
```

```
CAT(example_struct_, postfix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть оператор `##`, который производит макрорасширение своих аргументов, а потом конкатенирует результат:

```
#define EXAMPLE_MACRO(val_type, postfix) \
    struct example_struct_ ## postfix {  \
        val_type val;                    \
    };
```

См. [подробности](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators) в любом справочнике по языку в разделе с макросами.